# Bind to CoreWindow event

Tags: c++, xaml, uwp

I want to bind to Window::Current->CoreWindow->GetForCurrentThread()->KeyDown event (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.corewindow.keydown?view=winrt-19041). I tried:

```
Window::Current->CoreWindow->GetForCurrentThread()->KeyDown += Event_KeyDown;

void View3D::Event_KeyDown(Platform::Object^, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::KeyRoutedEventArgs^)
{
    OutputDebugString(L"HERE\r\n");
}
```

but I have an error:

> C++ function cannot be called with the given argument list
>   argument types are: (void (Platform::Object ^,
>   Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::KeyRoutedEventArgs ^e))            object
>   type is: Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow ^

Comment: Hi, can the following method help? Have you solved your issue?

Comment: Yes, I have solved it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

First, the parameters of KeyDown event are CoreWindow and KeyEventArgs, then when you try to subscribe the KeyDown event, you need to provide a handler function. For example:

.h:

```
void Event_KeyDown(Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow^ sender, Windows::UI::Core::KeyEventArgs^ e);
```

.cpp:

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Window::Current->CoreWindow->GetForCurrentThread()->KeyDown += ref new Windows::Foundation::TypedEventHandler< Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow^, Windows::UI::Core::KeyEventArgs^>(this, &MainPage::Event_KeyDown);

}

void MainPage::Event_KeyDown(Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow^ sender, Windows::UI::Core::KeyEventArgs^e)
{
    OutputDebugString(L"HERE\r\n");
}
```

For more information about Events in C++/CX, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/events-c-cx?view=vs-2019#consuming-events-in-windows-components).